# Java program with Input/Output does not finish running (hangs)

Tags: java, netbeans

This is my first assignment on NetBeans running a java code for clean up and formatting. I have not previous experience in any other programming language. After I run the file, it never ends running. I don't know what to look for. I tried a few suggestions, including the light bulb's ones on the sideline but it didn't work. (*the code was given and not changed)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputOutput { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Using print statements */
        System.out.println("Print first ");
        System.out.println("Print second ");

        /* Using println statements */
        System.out.println("Print third");
        System.out.println("Print fourth");
        System.out.println("Print fifth");

        /* Create a scanner for inputs */
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        /* Get the color and display it */
        System.out.println("What is your favorite color?");
        String color = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You wrote: " + color);

        /* Get the num of apples and display */
        System.out.println("How many apples do you have?");
        int numApples = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You wrote: " + numApples);

        /* Close the scanner */
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it "never ends running"?  I ran your code, and it terminated fine.

Comment: please show the input/output **edit** works fine for me

Comment: Perhaps you should add a message to the end of your code that prints a message saying the program is done.

Comment: When you ran the program, did you press Enter after typing your favourite colour, and again after the number of apples?

Comment: this is the only output: run
Print first 
Print second 
Print third
Print fourth
Print fifth
What is your favorite color?

Comment: I didn't type my favorite color...or number of apples, because i didn't know i was supposed to. where?

Comment: at the end of the program the box reads: inputoutput #15 (running) same as the previous ones.  this is the only output: run Print first Print second Print third Print fourth Print fifth What is your favorite color?
I didn't type my favorite color...or number of apples, because i didn't know i was supposed to. where?

Comment: @Robtwoll look at this link, it explains where you have to make your input http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653871/how-do-i-get-input-from-system-in-java-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Type your favorite color into the console and press enter. The program is hanging because it expects to SCAN a line. Before you type, there is nothing to scan.

Answer (score 0):

Your java program is still waiting for input.

When ran from a terminal window (or from the prompt), you will simply start typing from there.

However, in your case, you run in from within netbeans. Netbeans will gather the output in the 'output' window. The same window will also be used for gathering terminal input. Simply make sure you click within the window that did your output, and when you start typing, you should see your typing appear. Hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to accept the entry, and move your code further along, and possibly enter the next line of information.