# Netbeans, input when testing single java files

Tags: java, file, input, netbeans

Edit: I forgot to mention that this is on the Linux version of Netbeans. I have tried in different desktop environments. **This is not a duplicate. It seems like a bug in Netbeans on Linux.**

I have never used netbeans before and still new to java itself. On eclipse and dr java, I could test run a single java source file and Scanner class input would work in the output panel.

On netbeans 12.1 I can't figure out how to do this. A simple test like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Umami {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;

        Scanner typeIt = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What's the password? --> ");
        input = typeIt.nextLine();

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("VISION")) {
            System.out.println("Acceptable!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unacceptable!");
        }
    }
}
```

I go to Run > Run File, output shows but I don't see any place for input, keyboard unresponsive.
Does it have to be a full project or can single java snippets be tested like this?

Comment: If I recall correctly you don't need a project to run a single java file. When you run the file you should see the console in the bottom half of the screen prompting you to enter input. It is possible that the windows is hidden - in that case, I'll try to unhide it from the Windows menu.

Comment: Which Window is that? I have Output open. Is there a different one that allows input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get input from System.in (Java) in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653871/how-do-i-get-input-from-system-in-java-in-netbeans). I ran your program and it was `ACCEPTABLE!` when I entered `VISION` :-) (You don't see the prompt until after you have entered your data).

Comment: Change the prompt from `print` to `println` to see it before you enter your response: `System.out.println("What's the password? --> ");`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question. I am at the Output pane, the prompt text shows but the keyboard does nothing. It looks like this is a problem with the GUI. I forgot to mention that this is on Linux.

Comment: Yes,  the output pane is where you need to be. That is where you type your input.